# Need to design a custom route in ASP.NET MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url-routing

I have designed a custom route which looks like below

"\client\{CLIENTCODE}\{Controller}\{View}\{id}"

other than this route I also have default MVC route intact.

The {CLIENTCODE} is 4 character length string in the URL,which will be used to detect a connection string and do operation on respective database.

I am facing two issues

1. All Ajax request take default route when I use AJAX URL as 'Controller\View'. How can I append {CLIENTCODE} to every AJAX request.
2. I am loosing {CLIENTCODE} from URL after the session expires and I am unable to get it in  Global.ASAX.

Answer (score 1):

If u need append this route to ajax request you need set the ajax url with your route.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.RouteUrl("routeName", new { code="code", controller="controller", action="action"})',            
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (data) {
            $("#product-attribute-values").append(data);
        }
    })
```

And what you mean 'loosing when session expired'? You can acces all route values with code like this in global.asax

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
    {
        string code = Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["code"].ToString();
    }
```